# Set cfn deletion policy for RDS instance using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a CDK stack that includes an RDS instance. I want to make sure the DB instance never gets deleted. I can't figure out how to set the deletion policy via CDK.

It looks like I can set deletion protection like this:

```
this.database = new rds.DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot(this, 'backendAPIDatabase', {
  snapshotIdentifier: this.props.snapshotIdentifier,
  instanceIdentifier: this.props.environmentName,
  engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.POSTGRES,
  instanceClass: this.props.databaseInstanceSize,
  vpc: this.vpc,
  multiAz: this.props.databaseMultiAz,
  enablePerformanceInsights: true,
  parameterGroup,
  allocatedStorage: this.props.allocatedDatabaseStorage
});

(this.database.node.defaultChild as rds.CfnDBInstance).deletionProtection = true;
```

But I can't figure out how to apply a deletion policy as a second backup.

Comment: Can you share the full code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it by using removalPolicy property. You should also set deletion protection via the constructor as shown below.

```
this.database = new rds.DatabaseInstanceFromSnapshot(this, 'backendAPIDatabase', {
    ...,
    deletionProtection: true,
    removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN
});
```

Comment: Thanks. How about if it's set up using fromDatabaseInstanceAttributes? Is (this.database.node.defaultChild as rds.CfnDBInstance).applyRemovalPolicy(cdk.RemovalPolicy.RETAIN); the only way to do it

Comment: I guess so, I cannot see any API to change the properties for an existing instance, however the defaults are already RemovalPolicy=Retain and DeletionProtection=true.